# Access AWS Root User account using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

AWS Root user account details

Is there any API by which we can get information of the AWS root user account details?

```
   ListUsersRequest request = new ListUsersRequest();
   ListUsersResult response = iam.listUsers(request);
   response.getUsers()
```

The code list all users not the root user account details

Comment: Hmm? It may be me but this question makes little sense to me. Reason: if you are the root user you don't need the details(you have them already) and if you are not you should never be able to get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root user is not an IAM user, so it won't appear in the list of IAM users.

If you don't mind me asking, what are you trying to access the root user for?

You can create a set of access keys for the root user and have java connect via those access keys.

Info on how to generate root user access keys can be found [here, in the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html#id_root-user_manage_add-key).

Java can be configured to use access credentials as noted [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/credentials.html).

I must warn you though, it is EXTREMELY bad practice to ever use your root credentials for things like this. Depending on what you're trying to do, you should ideally aim to use IAM users and roles instead of the root credentials.

Comment: I would like to retrieve the details of the accesskeys, whether MFa enabled on root user.

Comment: `GetAccountSummary` and you're after the `AccountMFAEnabled` field: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetAccountSummary.html in Java: http://javadox.com/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.3.14/com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/AmazonIdentityManagement.html

Comment: Thanks !! That was helpful. Can you also provide some information about how to get the statements for iam policies. I'm able to get iam policy name but the statement i.e what permissions and which resources...

Comment: IAM policies can get tricky, but luckily there is a policy generator online - play around with it and see what different api calls are available: https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html . To have a User or Role perform `GetAccountSumary`, you'll need to attach the following policy to them: In awspolicygen: set the type of policy to `AWS IAM`, then for aws services set that to `identity and Access Management`, under actions search for `GetAccountSummary`, for the arn put `*`. Click Generate and that is the policy you attach to the user or role.